# If linux can support NTFS file system then why cannot it be installed on same?

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, ntfs

After learning basics of installation and types of file system, I found that Linux(Ubuntu) can open,create and delete file on an NTFS file system, where as windows can't even see ext series! so my question if Linux can scan and modify the file operations on NTFS why can't it be installed on an NTFS partition (irrespective of Primary or Logical).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is mainly because Linux has a strict permissions policy for its OS, from the user's directory on to the kernel. These permissions are not supported by the NTFS file system.

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) for an interesting comparison on file systems.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/74851/62612), it **is** possible to use POSIX file system permissions on NTFS. I have not tried it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from permission issues and POSIX compatibility, the NTFS filesystem check utilities are not capable of fixing all the issues that Windows' `chkdsk.exe` can. 
This is not an issue when dual-booted with Windows (unless you don't have a separate `/boot` partition, in which case everything would be unbootable). Simply-put, the NTFS drivers available for Linux are not feature-complete.